# Resolve swift array index out of bounds issue

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to remember swift array function which will return to me element by index.

Let say I have 7 elements in the swift array, but I am passing index = 10 or 100 to it. Xcode will throw an error with the index out of bounds message.

What I am trying to achieve is trying to iterate array somehow starting from 0.

So in case, I called element with index number 10, the swift array should return for me element with index number 2 assuming that array starts from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to cycle back around? If that is the case then you want to use modular arithmetic like this: `array[index % array.count]`.

Comment: oh yeah looks like this is a solution, I supposed maybe there is some Swifty thing for this)